# How to quantify the overlap of 2 distribution

Tags: hypothesis-testing, lognormal-distribution, overlapping-data

I have three events in time that follows a Lognormal distribution and that, in theory, occur in order `T0` then `T1` then `T2`.

`T0` is the start of the whole process and `T3` is the end. But this is in theory and in fact, I need the be sure that `T2` actually consistently **never** occure after `T3`. And if it is verified, by how much it consistently occurs before `T3` ? (Actually, if the theory is verified, the rare case were `T2` occurs closely before `T3` will define the maximum amount of time our application can run).

I know that Cohen's d provide some answer but it is for normal distribution, isn't it ? Any relevant metrics ?

Comment: This doesn't read like an "overlap" question: it's a matter of describing a bivariate distribution on the support $T_2\le T_3.$  Because there are too many solutions, could you provide more details of what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: We need to measure the moment when 3 muscles activate. One that activate at ``T0``, and one at ``T2``, when the one in the middle activate at ``T1``, a software analyse the signal to make somme actions, but it has to decide what to do before ``T3`` occur. So I need to "proove" that there is at least ``S`` second available between ``T2`` and ``T3`` so that the software have enought time to process the data. (Actually, ``T0`` is not that relevant to solve that particular problem)

Comment: Why not just measure the time elapsed between the two events and study those measurements??

Comment: indeed, but i 'am not used to it. I mean, what i have to show ? do i only have to find the 100th percentile and say "every other moment of activation in time is earlier than this one so that is ok" ?